# error sending mail, dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1025: getsockopt: connection refused, docker, mhsendmail

Tags: php, docker, email, mailhog

**Dockerfile**

```
COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes --quiet ca-certificates curl git &&\
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl -Lsf 'https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz' | tar -C '/usr/local' -xvzf -
ENV PATH /usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
RUN go get github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail
RUN cp /root/go/bin/mhsendmail /usr/bin/mhsendmail
RUN echo 'sendmail_path = /usr/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr mailhog:1025' > /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:

  GKapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: GKapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: GKapp
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    ports:
      - "1025:1025"
      - "8025:8025"
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Stuff I'm tyring as follows:-

```
docker exec -it GKapp bash
```

```
cat /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
sendmail_path = /usr/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr mailhog:1025
```

```
/usr/bin/mhsendmail --help
Usage of /usr/bin/mhsendmail:
  -f, --from string        SMTP sender (default "www@2693eda79e6e")
  -i, --long-i             Ignored. This flag exists for sendmail compatibility. (default true)
  -o, --long-o             Ignored. This flag exists for sendmail compatibility. (default true)
  -t, --long-t             Ignored. This flag exists for sendmail compatibility. (default true)
      --smtp-addr string   SMTP server address (default "localhost:1025")
  -v, --verbose            Verbose mode (sends debug output to stderr)
```

```
/usr/bin/mhsendmail andy@mailhog.local <<EOF
From: Andy <kinsta@mailhog.local>
To: Test <test@mailhog.local>
Subject: Hello, Andy!

Hey there,
Missing you pig time.

Hogs & Kisses,
Andy
EOF
error sending mail
2022/08/31 12:52:42 dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1025: getsockopt: connection refused
```

So, I'm unable to send an email using mailhog from within the container and from a script on the local file-system also:-

**email.php**

```
<?php

$to = "test@mailhog.local";
$subject = "Hey, I’m Pi Hog Pi!";
$body = "Hello, MailHog!";
$headers = "From: pihogpi@kinsta.com" . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

echo 'email sent';
```

None of the above methods work? help.

Comment: https://github.com/mailhog/mhsendmail/issues/25

Comment: not sure that link helps me much?

Comment: it describing solutions for your issue